# Calculating the circumference with C# Windows Forms App

Tags: c#

For school, I have to create a calculator where you enter the radius of a circle and it calculates the circumference and the area.

I tried coding it and everything I tried just won't work. It kept giving me errors along the lines of it having difficulty converting the textbox into a double, and other errors. This is my code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Circumference
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            txtCircumference = Math.PI * Math.Pow(txtRadius, 2);
            txtArea = 2 * Math.PI * txtRadius;


        }
    }
}
```

I'm used to coding with python so C# is kinda out of my comfort zone.

Comment: `txtRadius` would usually refer to the text box control itself, while `txtRadius.Text` would get the actual value, on which you’d use `double.TryParse` to see if it’s valid

Comment: @stuartd tried using ```cs temp = Math.PI * Math.Pow(int.parse(txtRadius.Text), 2);
            txtCircumference.Text = temp.ToString();``` and it gave me an error saying that 'temp' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Please update your post with your code rather than posting code in the comments

Answer (score 2):

You may be new to C# but the most glaring issue is with WinForm controls.  My answer assumes that `txtRadius`, `txtCircumference`, and `txtArea` are all `TextBox` controls.

Note I am writing this freeform and not in a VS editor so I may have errors.

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!double.TryParse(txtRadius.Text, out double radius))
    {
        throw new Exception("Radius is a not a valid double.");
    }
    txtCircumference.Text = (Math.PI * radius * radius).ToString();
    txtArea.Text = (2.0 * Math.PI * radius).ToString();
}
```

Observe that each `TextBox` has a `.Text` string property.  For me to interchange a double with a string requires me to parse the string into a double, or else use ToString() to write the double as a string.